# scipy.optimize.linprog seems to solve the task but doesn't return the x?

Tags: scipy, linear-programming

I'm trying to solve a very simple linear program using scipy.optimize.linprog, and it seems the function does what I want it to do, but somehow it doesn't return the 'x' (it does return the correct minimal function value)

Just for a simple example (in matlab notation), I have a 2-D a=[a1; a2] and simple linear constraint [1, 2] * a = 1, and want to minimize the L1 norm of a. The optimum should be a=[0, 0.5].

As far as I understand, I can formulate this in standard form by using an extra variable s, such that b>=abs(a) (i.e. a-b<=0 and -a-b<=0) and minimize sum(b) subject to these constraints and the original equality constraint [1, 2] * a = 1.

So I define x= [a; b], plug it into scipy's linprog, it returns with a success, and I get the correct answer: optimal value of sum(b) is 0.5. However, the x that it returns is full of nan's instead of [0; 0.5; 0; 0.5]

Here's the code:

```
A = np.array([1,2]).reshape([1,2])
b_eq = np.array([1])
ones = np.ones([2,])
zeros = np.zeros([2,])
zerosm = np.zeros([1, 2])
eye = np.eye(2)
c = np.hstack([zeros, ones])
A_ub = np.vstack([np.hstack([eye, -eye]), np.hstack([-eye, -eye])])
b_ub = np.hstack([zeros, zeros])
A_eq = np.hstack([A, zerosm])
res = scipy.optimize.linprog(c, A_ub=A_ub, b_ub=b_ub, bounds=(None, None),
                             A_eq=A_eq, b_eq=b_eq)
```

The result:

```
success: True
 status: 0
    fun: 0.5
      x: array([ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan])
    nit: 3
  slack: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.])
message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
```

I.e. x is nan's instead of the solution. The function value is correct (0.5), and slacks seem fine - according to the scipy docs slack of 0 means that the constraint is active, so 1st and 3rd zero mean that a1=b1=0, and the 2nd zero means a2=b2 and they are not zero (otherwise the 4th slack would also be 0). This is again expected as [0, 0.5] is the solution.

What am I doing wrong? Is this a bug? (using scipy 0.15.1)

Thanks!

Comment: @warren-weckesser Sorry, copy pasting error when I was simplifying the question, it's supposed to be A, edited now

Comment: Thanks.  When I run your code with scipy 0.18.0, I get `x: array([ 0. ,  0.5,  0. ,  0.5])` and `nit: 4`.  The other attributes of the result are the same as yours.

Comment: I see, so it seems I wasted my time on an old bug.. Thanks!

Comment: How do I give you credit here? I'd accept your answer if you post it

Comment: I'll make my comment an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you are running into a bug that has been fixed since version 0.15.1.

When I run your code with scipy 0.18.0, I get:

```
In [3]: import scipy.optimize

In [4]: %paste
A = np.array([1,2]).reshape([1,2])
b_eq = np.array([1])
ones = np.ones([2,])
zeros = np.zeros([2,])
zerosm = np.zeros([1, 2])
eye = np.eye(2)
c = np.hstack([zeros, ones])
A_ub = np.vstack([np.hstack([eye, -eye]), np.hstack([-eye, -eye])])
b_ub = np.hstack([zeros, zeros])
A_eq = np.hstack([A, zerosm])
res = scipy.optimize.linprog(c, A_ub=A_ub, b_ub=b_ub, bounds=(None, None),
                             A_eq=A_eq, b_eq=b_eq)

## -- End pasted text --

In [5]: res
Out[5]: 
     fun: 0.5
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nit: 4
   slack: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.])
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([ 0. ,  0.5,  0. ,  0.5])
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to solve your problem with `scipy 1.3.1` and it works well:

```
con: array([  7.07545134e-12])
     fun: 0.49999999999882094
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nit: 4
   slack: array([  1.07107656e-11,  -4.48552306e-12,  -4.75552930e-12,
         1.00000000e+00])
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([ -7.73314746e-12,   5.00000000e-01,   2.97761815e-12,
         5.00000000e-01])
```